# idlj parameter invalid argument -td mac?

Tags: corba, idlj

Im trying to follow a tutorial to do a CORBA assignment.

project 
-Client/HelloClient.java
-Server/HelloServer.java
-Hello.idl

I do the first step, trying to compile the IDL (from the project root), and it fails.
`$ idlj –td Client –fclient Hello.idl`

```
com.sun.tools.corba.se.idl.InvalidArgument: Invalid argument:  –td.
```

java version "1.8.0_11"

```
$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 juliusskye  staff  102 Oct 28 20:14 Client
-rw-r-----@ 1 juliusskye  staff   85 Oct 28 17:49 Hello.idl
drwxr-xr-x  3 juliusskye  staff  102 Oct 28 17:52 Server
-rw-r--r--  1 juliusskye  staff  425 Oct 29 13:45 idljintro.iml
drwxr-xr-x  2 juliusskye  staff   68 Oct 29 13:45 src
```

I found [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1177969?tstart=0) which says CORBA has problems parsing paths with / in front. But mine doesn't have a /

Comment: If you also need to do an assignment with C++, check TAOX11, that is a very easy to use implementation using C++11. We provide free evaluation licenses for students to use in assignments.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the Lecturer's instructions were wrong or outdated or the compiler is not fully working but compilation of all files is achieved by

```
idlj -fall hello.idl
```